# Why do browsers on my primary monitor render some colors with a different color code than on my secondary monitor?

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, colors

Note: I'm not talking about a difference in apparent color to my eyes/monitor calibration here. I've got the following icon:

[image]

And genuinely, if I open the icon in a paint program, its color is mostly FFC240...

But when it's showing in a browser window (Chrome, or Electron actually.. edit: and also Edge) on my primary monitor, its color code is F7BF4F:

[image]

If I move the window really slowly (window contents visible while dragging) there's a moment when the browser window is just > 50% onto the secondary monitor, that the icon visibly brightens up and becomes more orange. This is to say that if the icon is nearer the left edge of the browser, then it will stay the F7BF4F color until the browser window is just over half way onto the second monitor, at which point the colors of the pixels change.

It seems to be only browsers that do this: If I take a snip of the icon (like i did above) and move the snip window between monitors, it remains whatever color it was when I took the snip (which changes according to which monitor the browser was on)

Other things seem variably affected too; chrome browser's window title bar is 8F8FD5 when on the primary monitor, and 8E8CD8 on the secondary. Electron and Firefox browsers' title bars are the same 8E8CD8 all the time, and FF draws the icon as FFC240 all the time, but Electron changes the icon color depending on the monitor.. This gives me all the variations: Chrome changes both its title bar and the icon, Electron changes the icon but not its title bar, FF changes nothing

What do I need to turn off to get colors on the primary monitor to be drawn as true all the time?

Comment: Color calibration could be reflected on screenshots in Windows. What OS are you using? Do you have non-default color profiles enabled?

Comment: Windows 10, no color calibrations that I'm aware of. If it's relevant it's a laptop with 2 gfx cards - the internal panel is (i think) driven by an Intel chipset and the external monitors (an HP and a DELL) are driven by an nvidia one. The primary monitor is the DELL, displayport connection. The secondary monitor is hdmi-dvi and the internal is whatever it is. The internal panel and the secondary monitor behave the same, color wise

Comment: It's not the GPUs, or the difference in screen manufacturer, it's in the icc profiling - which unless it has been done properly, will just be a generic "close enough for jazz" profile supplied by the manufacturer. Good enough for your phone pictures, but nowhere near accurate enough for a true colour workflow.

Comment: Why do some apps (chrome) obey the ICC profiling and not others (FF)

Comment: Lousy standards adoption ;) tbh for web you should always work sRGB, for those browsers that always assume it, or ignore actual embedded profiles.

Comment: I have an answer below, but if it's going to pull downvotes from Windows users who simply don't understand how truly poor Windows' colour management consistency is, then it's gone. Figure it out for yourselves, or get an OS that can actually manage colour properly. I'm done.

Comment: I've always felt that downvotes should have a mandatory comment about how the post could be improved even if it wasn't public.. Ive given up on giving a damn about the points/rep and just focus on helping ten people for one of them to say thanks..  wasn't my DV by the way - I found it useful (only just read and digested it - been a busy week!) even if some other passer by covertly judged otherwise

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Some windows apps, even after all these years, just don't handle profiling correctly. It is a mess. Windows doesn't really have any 'authority' apps must go through to ensure standards are followed. Google apps on the Mac sometimes go their own way too & ignore simple toolbox standards; fortunately, almost every other app on a Mac can accurately read & work with the machine's profiling - whether or not that profiling is actually accurate is another matter - to do it properly there's no way round having to buy a colorimeter, but at least you know once you did, it's going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there's nothing to "turn off" to achieve this.

What you need is accurate colour calibration. Without it you don't actually know which is correct, if either.
What you are seeing is the independent profiles for each of your displays being handed off as you transition the image from one to the other. Some systems & structures can do this 'live' so you never get that 50% effect, but others can only balance to one or the other, so you see a sudden shift if both profiles are not accurate.

I can confirm that the numbers you are reading are approximately what my fully-calibrated system can see, but as the conversion required to register that in sRGB is a 'double guess' one from the apparent colour, via the screen's native colour, then to the colour icc profile, then I don't actually know what you are actually seeing, only what your colour checker is telling you.

Calibration *can* be done by eye, but without an accurate colorimeter & accompanying software, you will never achieve a known start-point, so never know if either screen is actually correct.

Comment: I'm not so much bothered about "correct" in the sense of "is this color even orange, to my eyes" .. but I would like it to show the same pixel color code on both monitors. Are you saying that there is a calibration step that means some (but not all - white, black and superusers' #242729 black bar at the top, are the same on both monitors) colors are shifted as a pixel code before theyre drawn?

Comment: The color picker (and I've tried two now) is seeing the pixels after they're shifted.. whereas if I open that icon in a paint program, i'm told its orange color is FFC240 (which is what I want my color picker tool to tell me regardless of monitor/browser). As noted I don't really care if the calibration is so out of whack that it looks purple or green to my eyes, so long as the color code is still FFC240. Also, why do some apps change its color and not others, if it's a gfx card/monitor calibration thing?

Comment: Colour are shifted twice before they're drawn, from the [sometimes assumed] sRGB on the web or document 'page', to your screen's native values, then back through the [calibrated or not] icc profile back into numbers for your screen measuring tool. Some tools can measure native or other assumed profiles, but that's probably beyong your requirement for this. You should assume a constant sRGB workflow for anything vaguely 'web-based'.

Comment: If you want to deep-dive into Windows color calibration quirks, there's an [interesting video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPubgoqtfbk) about this.

Comment: @gronostaj - Windows abysmal colour-workflow management & standardisation is one of the reasons I've never used Windows for colour work ;-)

Comment: I tried to get a photo of what I see on the Mac if I expand that icon across both my screens & then check by eye & also with the colour meter… but daylight interference is a bit distracting. I can show that I get identical colour on both screens, by eye & by meter, but it doesn't come out at the exact colours in the photo [so that would just cloud the issue]